# How to search recursively by key of a multi-dim array?

Tags: php, arrays, json, search, recursion

I am trying to create a recursive function that takes an array and looks for a property name `children`, and constructs an array out of the matching one.

This is not straight forward because I don't know which block of my JSON data will contain the key `children`, so I decided to write a recursive function.

---

I've tried

```
$testDataJson = '
{
    "macAddress": "10:20:30:40:50:81",
    "type": "HGW",
    "children": [{
        "macAddress": "98:D6:D6:D8:FF:34",
        "pendingMethods": false,
        "lastSeen": "2017-05-24T10:36:35",
        "lastSeenLight": "GREEN",
        "model": "AP7465CE-TN",
        "type": "WIRELESS_ACCESS_POINT"
    }, {
        "macAddress": "44:66:E9:A1:2C:DC",
        "pendingMethods": false,
        "lastSeen": "2017-05-24T10:39:01",
        "lastSeenLight": "GREEN",
        "model": "PLC 200+ DIV -TN",
        "type": "POWERLINE"
    }, {
        "macAddress": "D8:C2:A9:1C:44:47",
        "pendingMethods": "False",
        "lastSeen": "2017-05-24T10:39:01",
        "lastSeenLight": "GREEN",
        "model": "PG9073",
        "type": "POWERLINE",
        "children": [{
            "macAddress": "22:CD:E6:8F:8C:B8",
            "pendingMethods": false,
            "lastSeen": "2017-05-24T10:38:16",
            "lastSeenLight": "GREEN",
            "model": "PG9073",
            "type": "POWERLINE"
        }, {
            "macAddress": "13:E4:AB:33:36:AC",
            "pendingMethods": false,
            "lastSeen": "2017-05-24T10:29:13",
            "lastSeenLight": "GREEN",
            "model": "PG9072",
            "type": "POWERLINE_WIRELESS_ACCESS_POINT"
        }]
    }]
}';
$testDataArray = json_decode($testDataJson,true);

function recursiveKeyFinder($array) {
    $result = [];
    if (!isset($array['children']) AND is_array($array)) {
       return $result;
    }else {
        foreach($array['children'] as $child){
            $result['macAddress'] = $child['macAddress'];
        }
        return recursiveKeyFinder($array);
    }
}
var_dump(recursiveKeyFinder($testDataArray));
```

Result: Nothing from `var_dump()`.

---

Desired result:

```
["macAddress": "98:D6:D6:D8:FF:34",
"macAddress": "44:66:E9:A1:2C:DC",
"macAddress": "D8:C2:A9:1C:44:47",
"macAddress": "22:CD:E6:8F:8C:B8",
"macAddress": "13:E4:AB:33:36:AC"]
```

---

How can I investigate this?

Comment: You have infinite recursion. You're making the recursive call with the same array you were given. You're also never returning the `$result` that you modify in the `foreach` loop.

Comment: What is the result you're trying to get?

Comment: Driving home now will update as soon as I'm home. I'm trying return my result array and make my function work. I'll add more details

Comment: You can't code and drive at the same time? You'll never make it in this business. :)

Comment: @Barmar : I updated my post added my desired result that I am trying to get out of my malfunction recursive function.

Comment: I just re-read your question, and it seems that I overlooked the caveat that you don't know where your children are.  Furthermore, you DON"T want to extract the first `macAddress` listed.  I have adjusted my code to provide the correct result per your posted input, but can you show me an alternative data sample so that I can see if it works for all cases that you might encounter?

Comment: Your accepted answer does not provide your desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Barmar siad "You have infinite recursion."

This is my solution. It prints out all mac address

```
function recursiveKeyFinder($array) {
    $result = [];

    $result[] = $array['macAddress'];
    if (isset($array['children'])) {
        foreach($array['children'] as $child){
            $result = array_merge($result,recursiveKeyFinder($child));
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Here the result

```
array (size=6)
  0 => string '10:20:30:40:50:81' (length=17)
  1 => string '98:D6:D6:D8:FF:34' (length=17)
  2 => string '44:66:E9:A1:2C:DC' (length=17)
  3 => string 'D8:C2:A9:1C:44:47' (length=17)
  4 => string '22:CD:E6:8F:8C:B8' (length=17)
  5 => string '13:E4:AB:33:36:AC' (length=17)
```

Hope this can help

Answer (score 2):

PHP already offers a specific tool for this operation: `array_walk_recursive()`; so there is no need to reinvent the wheel.

Your task can be swiftly, concisely completed with just one function call after preparing your json data.

Omitting the first `macAddress` (unwanted) value is done by passing only the subarray with the key of 'children' to `array_walk_recursive()`.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e87a4fde9a6094a4c0f328a919a03c9d890aeeb3))

```
$array=json_decode($testDataJson,true)['children'];  // this avoids including the first "non-children" macAddress value.
array_walk_recursive($array,function($v,$k)use(&$result){if($k==='macAddress') $result[]=$v;});
var_export($result);
```

Result:

```
array (
  0 => '98:D6:D6:D8:FF:34',
  1 => '44:66:E9:A1:2C:DC',
  2 => 'D8:C2:A9:1C:44:47',
  3 => '22:CD:E6:8F:8C:B8',
  4 => '13:E4:AB:33:36:AC',
)
```

---

Alternatively, the input array can be prepared like this:

```
$array=array_diff_key(json_decode($testDataJson,true),['macAddress'=>'']);
```

This will ensure you don't accidentally grab any non-children `macAddress` values.